# concat field values of an array of objects

Tags: c#, string

```
private readonly List<A> _previousDayPrices;    

private void PrintDebugPreviousDayPrice(DateTime date)
{
    var str = "";
    foreach (var d in _previousDayPrices.Take(2))
    {
        str += d.Price;
        str += "-";
        str += d.Date;
        str += "-";
        str += d.EuroExchangeRateDate;
        str += "-";
        str += d.EuroExchangeRate;
        str += ",";
    }
}
```

What is the linq manner to do this or is there a string's method ?

Comment: have you tried using string.join()

Comment: @kyle:yes without success

Comment: @zey:will try it sounds good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try linq like this :

```
string.Join(",", this._previousDayPrices.Take(2).Select(d => string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}", d.Price, d.Date,d.EuroExchangeRateDate, d.EuroExchangeRate)).ToArray());
```

Comment: for .net 4.0 you can skip `ToArray`

Comment: +1 for an elegant answer, using `Linq`, as requested.

Comment: You forgot the Take(2) after `_previousDayPrices`

Answer (score 0):

That's the way your code may be improved

```
private readonly List<AnItemType> _previousDayPrices;
private void PrintDebugPreviousDayPrice(DateTime date)
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (AnItemType item in _previousDayPrices)
    {
        String valueToAppend = String.Format(
            "{0}-{1}-{2}-{3},",
            item.Price,
            item.Date,
            item.EuroExchangeRateDate,
            item.EuroExchangeRate);
        stringBuilder.Append(valueToAppend);
    }
}
```

Comment: the same here, don't forget the Take(2)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
        var result = string.Join(",", (from d in _previousDayPrices.Take(2) select 
               string.Join("-", {d.Price, 
                                 d.Date, 
                                 d.EuroExchangeRateDate,
                                 d.EuroExchangeRate})).ToArray());
```

This assumes that Price, Date, EuroExchangeRateDate and EuroExchangeRate are already strings (I doubt that based upon their names, but your sample points in this direction). If not, you need to convert them before.

Comment: you still need the foreach statement because he process 2 elements with Take(2)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I just updated my sample in order to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Try it ,

```
var res = _previousDayPrices.Take(2).Aggregate((i,j) => i.Price + "-" + i.Date + "-" + i.EuroExchangeRateDate +"-" + i.EuroExchangeRate + "," + 
        j.Price + "-" + j.Date + "-" + j.EuroExchangeRateDate +"-" + j.EuroExchangeRate +
        )
```